# How to fix " Use of unresolved identifier 'flowLayout' "

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Sorry for my bad english.

I am trying to create a collection view programmatically, but it says flowLayout is a unresolved identifier.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import RxSwift

class ChapterViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, 
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate {

private var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
var chapterName: String?
var bibleArray = BibleBooksMock().booksArray

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = chapterName
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
    myCollectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCell")
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a collectionViewLayout called flowLayout.

```
let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()        
self.myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
```

[Here's](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) a tutorial to help as can [this](http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-uicollectionview-in-swift-programmatically/) one for creating a custom CVLayout.

Also if you need to import UIKit there is no need to import Foundation because its included in UIKit.

Answer (score 3):

While I believe @Alex Bailey has a fantastic answer, I'd like to add more to it.

```
let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()        
self.myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
```

I want to get down as to why yours does NOT work and why this does. In yours, you have

```
self.myCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout
```

however, if you look at your code, there is NO variable called flowLayout. Therefore, Swift is looking for a variable called `flowLayout` that is not initialized beforehand. In the correct answer, we initialize `flowLayout` as

```
let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
```

Therefore, we know what `flowLayout` is: `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Therefore, in Swift, if you see an `unresolved identifier` error, you may not have initialized a variable you may have thought you did. This is generally a simple error to resolve.